# Retrieve medium blob from MySQL return only 13 bytes

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0

I searched lot and tried various methods but couldn't able to solve this problem.
i need to save image into mysql file.

i used below code to save image into database.

```
try
{
    string location = @"C:\Users\test\Downloads\Photos\batman-greenscreen.jpg";

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    UInt32 fileLength = (UInt32)fs.Length;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileLength];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileLength);

    string sqlPhotoQuery = "INSERT INTO tab_photo VALUES('" + photo.PhotoId + "','" + photo.ProjectID + "','" + photo.Day + "','" + photo.Barcode + "','" + photo.Photoname + "','" + photo.PhotoXml + "','" + buffer + "','" + fileLength + "')";
    int result = MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, sqlPhotoQuery);
    if (result > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

in this file image length is 12428,
[image: saving values]

what i tried for retrieve data from database:

```
Photo photo = new Photo();
try
{
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tab_photo where PhotoId='"+photoId+"'";
    MySqlDataReader rdr = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(connectionString, sqlQuery);
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        photo.PhotoId = rdr.GetString("PhotoId");
        photo.ProjectID = rdr.GetString("ProjectID");
        photo.Day = rdr.GetInt32("Day");
        photo.Barcode = rdr.GetString("Barcode");
        photo.Photoname = rdr.GetString("Photoname");
        photo.PhotoXml = rdr.GetString("PhotoXml");

        MemoryStream ms;
        UInt32 FileSize;
        Bitmap outImage;

        int fileSize = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("PhotoSize"));
        byte[] rawData = new byte[fileSize];
        rdr.GetBytes(rdr.GetOrdinal("Photo"), 0, rawData, 0, (Int32)fileSize);

        photo.imageByte = rawData;

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{}
```

but when i retrieve file it retrieve only for first 13 bytes. after that its value is **zero** and there are **differences in retrieve values**.

[image: retrieve values]

i have followed instructions mentioned in [Handling BLOB Data With Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-programming-blob.html).

according to that i have changed my settings as follows:
[image: MySql Workbench setting]

this is how data saved in database
[image: data in DB]

what are the reasons that i can't get correct values? is there any problem in data saving or data retrieving or database configurations?

Comment: What does the data look like on the database side? Does the `Insert` statement load the full `byte[] buffer` into the database?

Comment: @jordanhill123 i have added db sample as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have the correct data in the database. By concatenating the buffer into the query string, "System.Byte[]" will be inserted into the database, since the insert statement will basically look like

```
INSERT INTO tab_photo VALUES(...,'System.Byte[]', ...)";
```

Use parameterized queries as they do in the example, and you should be good.

Do not just concatenate strings from somewhere into your SQL queries. (And do not catch and swallow all exceptions in a method like this. That makes it really hard to debug in case of a failure.)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlhelpermembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlhelper-executenonquery-overload-2 explains that pretty well. Instead of `,'" + buffer + "',`, you would use `, @buffer,` and call it like `MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, sqlPhotoQuery, new MySqlParameter("@buffer", buffer));`. (Repeat that for all values to be safer against SQL injection attacks.)

Answer (score 2):

You are putting your binary data into a string to write it to the db, which will not work. Try following the method in the example URL that you posted, of passing the data blob using a @parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You are not `INSERT`ing data properly. Your `INSERT` statement reads:

```
string sqlPhotoInsert = "INSERT INTO tab_photo VALUES('" + ...
```

In order words, you are NOT using parametrized query to insert BLOB data - this could not possibly work well.

You must use parametrized queries. You can find working example in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-programming-blob.html) (scroll to `C#` example).